# How does Qt6's lazy evaluation for QProperty work?

Tags: qt, qt6

Qt6 introduced the QProperty class, that allows us to bind certain values to each other in C++ code, similar to how it's done in QML.

According to their [introduction](https://wiki.qt.io/QProperty), this mechanism makes use of lazy evaluation, which, in this context is explained such that bindings that depend on a changing QProperty are only evaluated once the depending value is actually read from, rather than every time the source property changes.

I tried to visualize this behavior by baking their example in code. So consider the following snippet:

```
QProperty<int> width;
QProperty<int> height;
QProperty<int> area;

int c = 0;
area.setBinding([&](){
    c++;
    return width * height;
});

width = 10;
height = 10;

width = 20;
width = 30;
width = 10;

qDebug() << c << area.value() << c;
```

My expected output would've been `0 100 1`, the actual output was `6 100 6`.

I conclude, that the binding was evaluated with every change of the `width` and `height` properties, rather than lazily once `area` is read from.

Why does this happen? Do I misunderstand how lazy eval is supposed to work here? Is there a different way to visualize the lazy evaluation behavior?

Comment: I think this is the key (from `QProperty::setBinding()` docs): "Whenever a dependency of the binding changes, the binding will be re-evaluated, and the property's value gets updated accordingly."

Comment: Seems to be the case. I don't get what their Lazy evaluation section is on about, then, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This behavior was changed in Qt 6.2](https://www.qt.io/blog/all-about-property-bindings-in-qt-6.2)

> when porting some of the properties of different Qt modules to the new bindable property system, we realized that for most of the properties deferred evaluation doesn't work well. Most of the existing code requires eager evaluation, and changing it to work with lazy evaluation without breaking the logic requires a lot of modifications and significant rewrites in some cases. This might also be true for the user code. So it was decided to use eager evaluation and add support of grouping property updates together, to minimize unnecessary recalculations and change notifications.

It is still possible to reduce the amount of binding evaluations done, by calling [`Qt::beginPropertyUpdateGroup();`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qproperty.html#beginPropertyUpdateGroup) and [`Qt::endPropertyUpdateGroup();`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qproperty.html#endPropertyUpdateGroup).

For the above example:

```
int c = 0;
area.setBinding([&](){
    c++;
    return width * height;
});

Qt::beginPropertyUpdateGroup();
width = 10;
height = 10;

width = 20;
width = 30;
width = 10;
Qt::endPropertyUpdateGroup();

qDebug() << c << area.value() << c;
```

Will now output `3 100 3`, as the binding will evaluate three times:

- Once upon creation
- twice after `Qt::endPropertyUpdateGroup()` has been called

  - once for width
  - once for height